# ¿Cómo contar ocurrencias con streams de Java 8?

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

Estoy pasando una app de `Java6` a [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), hay casos en el que tenemos que contar las ocurrencias de **un** `String` en una lista. Para ello usamos:

```
Collections.frequency(lista, stringALocalizar);
```

Creo que esta parte no deberia tocarse. Si, en cambio, tenemos que contar todos los `String` y sus ocurrencias a traves de toda la lista tenemos que iterar sobre la lista y usar un `HashMap<String, Integer>` para almacenar los resultados y no realizar las iteraciones extra que causaría `Collections.frequency`. Algo parecido a esto:

```
for (String stringALocalizar : lista) {
    if (mapaDeResultados.containsKey(stringALocalizar)) {
        mapaDeResultados.put(stringALocalizar, mapaDeResultados.get(stringALocalizar)+1);
    } else {
        mapaDeResultados.put(stringALocalizar, 1);
    }
 }
```

¿Cómo puedo conseguir el mismo resultado con los streams de [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puedes usar

```
Map<String, Long> ocurrencias = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Lo que hace es agrupar los elementos de la lista y contar las ocurrencias, `Function.identity()` indica que la agrupación es por cada cadena distinta de la lista y `Collectors.Counting()` regresa un `Collector` que cuenta los elementos del stream, este objeto regresa el conteo en una variable de tipo `Long` por eso se declara el mapa como `Map<String, Long>`.

Comment: Muchas gracias enrique, funciona perfecto y la explicación es simple y clara! +1 y V ;)